# Finding the sum of terms removed from a series given the amount of elements and the AM of the series before and after removing the terms.

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math

"A list with $2007$ positive integers is written on a board, such that the arithmetic mean of all the numbers is $12$. Then, seven consecutive numbers are erased from the board. The arithmetic mean of the remaining numbers is $11.915$."

This is part of a problem from a maths competition, and the solution showed that the the sum of the seven consecutive numbers is $(2007)(12)-(2000)(11.915)=254$, however I don't understand why this is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is finding sum of these seven consecutive integers.

Arithmetic Mean = Total Sum / Number of Values

Total sum is $2007\times 12=24084$

Sum of the remaining numbers after deleting seven consecutive integers is $(2007-7)\times 11.915=2000\times 11.915=23830$

Sum of seven consecutive integers is $24084-23830=254$